# Vertically center a div based on browser screen

Tags: css, height, center, vertical-alignment

is it possible to center a div vertically based on the browser screen height?

I have this

```
#success {
  height: 300px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

but this centers vertically to it's parent div, and not based on the browser screen height. Is there a way where I can achieve what I want? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you want the z-index property. Setting a z-index higher than  its parent will make it relative to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the div `position: fixed` and it will be positioned relative to the window.